# Как передать значение/массив в другой .php файл

Tags: php, mvc

Ребят, надеюсь на вашу помощь, что-то не выходит допилить авторизацию, выходить херня, даже мягко сказано.
В общем, юзал я smarty , либу для MVC , чтобы было всё шик. Да решил обойтись, встрял несколько раз на грабли, но понял в чём косяки были. Сейчас снёс и пробую нормально на чистом PHP допилить MVC.
Начну с кода, имеется файл:

```
<?php
    loadTemplate('header');
    loadTemplate('index');
    loadTemplate('footer');
?>
```

loadTemplate , простой include в виде функции. Там разбирать собственно нечего.
Но, мне нужно в файл index.php , который я загружаю, передать массив.
Как мне это реализовать? я пробовал в index.php инклюдить эту страницу где сам этот массив.
Через дефайну (define) я могу передавать только 1 значение. Собственно как реализовать?

Был ещё такой косяк, мне в этот index.php нужно за каким то хером, прикрутить header();
Но так как я ебобо, и понимаю что у меня тут header.php подключается а потом index, где собственно уже есть буквыыыы и нельзя использовать header();

Пока что, со 2ым, не сложно, просто я немного тупил в этот вечер.

Меня интересует больше первое.
В Smarty, была такая ерундовина, которая передавала значения
Выглядило это так:

```
<?php
          $smarty->assign(Передаваемое_значение, значение);
?>
```

Как передать значения/е?

Comment: а вы можете вместо _проливания воды_, конкретнее описать проблему? ) Честно говоря, прочитал дважды ваш пост, ниасилил: то ли вам массив куда-то надо передать, то ли вам буферизация нужна, чтоб header() не ругалась ...

Comment: Как костыль можете для хранения использовать глобальные переменные. Либо "обыграть" эту ситуацию используя классы (либо расширять родительским либо через статик)

Answer (score -1):

Выше предоставленный вами код к mvc отношения не имеет. Костылями передавать данные так же, не нужно. Можно добавлять данные в строку и через $_GET забирать. в 1 файле ссылку на второй файл делаем, и туда вписываем переменную

```
<a href="page2.php?name=<?= $var ?>">Page2</a>
```

во втором файле принимаем её:

```
$var = $_GET['name'];
```

Или же отправлять через форму. Файл 1:

```
<form method="post" action="page2.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="name_value">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Второй файл:

```
$var_value = $_POST['name'];
```

Но это не очень хороший "тон", про безопасность и говорить не стоит. Лучше почитайте про mvc.
Вот что нам говорит @xfg об mvc:

> Модель - это любая ваша бизнес-логика, всякие вычисления и запросы к
>   бд. То есть то, без чего приложение впринципе не имеет смысла.
>
> Контроллер - это посредник между моделью и видом. Он запрашивает
>   данные (вызывает методы) у модели и затем передает их в вид.
>
> Вид - с помощью полученных данных от контроллера рисует пользовательский
>   интерфейс.
>
> Смысл в том, чтобы отделить логику приложения от
>   представления. Представление ничего не знает о модели и наоборот.
>
> Нужна одна точка входа. Клиент всегда запрашивает только index.php,
>   оно там внутри на основе данных из запроса решает какой контроллер
>   создать и какой метод из контроллера выполнить. Всё.